# Make Changes to Built Random Forest Model

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I am pretty new to the model training with R. Recently, I have built a random forest model and now I wonder if there's any way that I could modify the already-built model(which was saved as a RDS file), so I can use it to predict on new data which is slightly different from the ones it was trained on?

Specifically, these new data missing one or two insignificant identifier column/variable (e.g. filename, user ID), and all I am trying to understand is if there's any way I can take out these variables from the built model so I can get some prediction without training the model again (as training models takes long time)?

Comment: If that ID variable was not in the X-matrix given to the RF modeling function, then you should not need to remove it.

Comment: So that means I should retrain the whole model corect?

Comment: Generally one would not include an "user ID" variable in your list of predictors because that would usually be individually identifiable. If you made such an error in the development of a rf model, it would probably be useless and should be discarded.

Comment: "UserId" as a variable is not included in the model, however when I train the rf model I wrote something like `randomForest(Identifier ~.-UnitId, train.data) `. In this case, should I still disregard the model then?

Comment: That would seem to imply that you mightt get away with providing dummy values to the variables that were excluded in the model. Seems rather clumsy but it might work. Without a data example we are only guessing.

Comment: Yes, giving a dummy variable as UniIt to the model is what I also thought. Just wondering if there's a smarter way of doing things...